# xcode objective c - when I call 2 methods - only the last called method runs and first one is skipped

Tags: objective-c, ios, avfoundation, avaudioplayer

```
-(void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag
{

    [self NextHeading]; // this plays an mp3 file

    [self NextHeadingMeaning]; // this plays an Mp3 file

}
```

Only `[self NextHeadingMeaning]` method is called and `NextHeading` method is missed each time

```
-(IBAction) NextHeading{ 
    [audio stop]; 

    NSString *Filename = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"CH%@S%@",Heading,Meaning];
    Filepath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:Filename ofType:@"mp3"]; 

    audio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:Filepath] error:NULL]; 

    audio.delegate = self; 
    [audio play]; 
    [Filename autorelease]; 
}

-(IBAction) NextHeadingMeaning { 
    [audio stop]; 

     NSString *Filename = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"CH%@S%@",bold**Chapter**bold, Meaning]; 
     Filepath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:Filename ofType:@"mp3"]; 

     audio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:Filepath] error:NULL]; 

     audio.delegate = self; 
     [audio play]; 
     [Filename autorelease]; 
}
```

Why is this happening and how can I resolve it ?

Please advice, thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure that `[self NextHeading]` isn't being called?  I suspect that `[self NextHeading]` is starting the playback of the MP3 file and then immediately returning.  `[self NextHeadingMeaning]` then runs and starts playing the second MP3 which stops the first MP3 from playing.

Comment: @mttrb - I just checked and found that it goes into [Self NextHeading] method by using nslog, but it does not plays the audio (mp3) file at all.   how do I solve this ?

Comment: I think we'll need to see your `NextHeading` and `NextHeadingMeaning` methods to see what is going on.

Comment: -(IBAction) NextHeading{  
    [audio stop];
    
    NSString *Filename = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"CH%@S%@",Heading,Meaning];
    
    Filepath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:Filename ofType:@"mp3"];
    audio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:Filepath] error:NULL];
    audio.delegate = self;
    [audio play];
    [Filename autorelease];
    
}

Comment: Next heading Meaning Method below

Comment: As I suspected.  The NextHeading method is starting the playback of the MP3 in the background and then immediately returns.  Before the playback even starts you call the second method which, presumably similar to the first, stops the audio and starts playing the second MP3.

Comment: -(IBAction) NextHeadingMeaning{  
    
    [audio stop];
    
    NSString *Filename = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"CH%@S%@",**bold**Chapter**bold**,Meaning];
    
    Filepath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:Filename ofType:@"mp3"];
    audio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:Filepath] error:NULL];
    audio.delegate = self;
    [audio play];
    [Filename autorelease];
    
}

Comment: @mttrb - how do I solve it then ? just to add on - when I play these methods separately they work absolutely fine.

many thanks for helping me :-)

Comment: I haven't really used AVAudioPlayer before so I'm not sure of the details.  However, it looks like you should be able to get notified when the audio of the first file finishes playing in the `audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:successfully:` delegate method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just used a single iVar (`audio`) as an player, and when you send `NextHeading` & `NextHeadingMeaning` message, the `audio` init with your `sound_1.mp3` file firstly (it'll take some seconds if the mp3 file is big), then at the next moment (your first mp3 file might not inited, or has inited, but stopped followed by next message), you redo the init action with another mp3 file (sound_2.mp3), and finally, when the second mp3 file init done, `audio` plays `sound_2.mp3`. That's why you think the `NextHeading` is skipped.

So, to solve this problem, you can use a `NSMutableArray` iVar (e.g. `audioPlayers`), and create a local `audio` for both `NextHeading` & `NextHeadingMeaning`, and push it to `audioPlayers`.

And I think it is better to preload sound files if you can. :)

---

EDIT:

There's a `playAtTime:` method instead of `play`, you can delay the second audio player's playing time by this method, just like this:

```
[audioPlayer playAtTime:(audioPlayer.deviceCurrentTime + delay)];
```

`delay` is in seconds (`NSTimeInterval`).

Comment: hey @kjuly - you are a super hero ! part 1 of the problem is solved by creating audio1 as an instance of AVaudioPlayer but now it has created **another problem** that now both the MP3 files starts at the same time.. I want them to start one-by-one. can you please help once again...

Comment: @Abhinav have a look at the new part of the answer. :)

Comment: @Abhinav - also take a look at [AVQueuePlayer](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVQueuePlayer_Class/Reference/Reference.html).  Sadly, this is not a drop-in replacement for [AVAudioPlayer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html).  For example, it doesn't have a delegate so you have to register for notifications.  However, if you want to player multiple sounds in sequence it may be best for you.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way that the first call is skipped, put a breakpoint in it or output something with NSLog() and you'll see. Most probable cause is that the first method doesn't do what you expect and this could be for various reasons - for example condition or specific timeout.

Edit:
After looking your code, it seems that you're missing some basic stuff like variable naming, variable scope and so. To simply make your code run, just replace the `NSString *Filename..` string from the second method and probably it'll work. A better choice would be to visit [Start Developing iOS Apps Today](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/Introduction/Introduction.html) and follow the roadmap.

Comment: hey @mspasov thanks for the reply, yes you are right it goes into the first method but does not plays the audio mp3 file. I have posted the methods above. can you please have a look and help. mttrb is also looking into it... many thanks :-)